# should these functions be marked @staticmethod, is so what value does this provide -- python

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

I am building a simple app that creates chord sheet objects that hold a root and all the notes in the major and minor triads for that root. It can also return the inversions. Later, I will work with flat notes and add more complicated chords to the base class (there is a chord notebook class that users can store selected chord sheets in, but that is unrelated). I am just doing this to practice concepts I am learning at the moment.

Should the get() methods and inversion() methods be static methods? If so, why? What value does this provide?

```
class Chord_Sheet:

    notes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]

    def __init__(self, root):
        index = self.notes.index(root)

        self.root = root
        self.major = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index+4)%12], self.notes[(index+7)%12]]
        self.minor = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index+3)%12], self.notes[(index+7)%12]]
        #self.perfect_fifth = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index+x)%12], self.notes[(index+x)%12]]
        #self.diminished_fifth = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index+x)%12], self.notes[(index+x)%12]]     
        #self.major_seventh = []
        #self.minor_seventh = []
        #self.diminished_seventh = []

    def get_root(self):  #static?
        return "Root: {}".format(self.root)

    def get_major(self):  #static?
        return "Major Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.major[0], self.major[1], self.major[2], self.major[0], self.major[2], self.major[1])

    def get_minor(self):  #static?
        return "Minor Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.minor[0], self.minor[1], self.minor[2], self.minor[0], self.minor[2], self.minor[1])

    def first_inverted_major(self):  #static?
        return "First Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.major[1], self.major[2], self.major[0], self.major[1], self.major[0], self.major[2])

    def first_inverted_minor(self):  #static?
        return "First Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.minor[1], self.minor[2], self.minor[0], self.minor[1], self.minor[0], self.minor[2])

    def second_inverted_major(self):  #static?
        return "Second Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.major[2], self.major[0], self.major[1], self.major[2], self.major[1], self.major[0])

    def second_inverted_minor(self):  #static?
        return "Second Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.minor[2], self.minor[0], self.minor[1], self.minor[2], self.minor[1], self.minor[0])
```

Comment: A function cannot be static if it references `self`. Since `get_root()` references `self.root`, it can't be static.

Comment: thanks, can you think of any reason why I might want to use a static method for this class?

Comment: Side-note: Returning formatted strings is nearly useless for programmatic usage. If you have a function that returns possible major chords, I'd suggest returning a `tuple` of `tuple`s of notes, rather than a string that describe them. For example, `get_major` might do `return (self.major[0], self.major[1], self.major[2]), (self.major[0], self.major[2], self.major[1])`, giving a programmatically useful set of options for the major chord (the caller can format it as they like if it's intended for output).

Comment: If I did it that way would I format it outside of the class, only when I actually need to display? I just wanted it to look good in the terminal.

Comment: @alpine.lines: `staticmethod` is basically only for utility functions specifically useful to a class that serve no purpose outside the class, but could just as easily be defined outside the class completely. `classmethod` is for alternate constructors. All other class methods (that actually use information about the instance) can and should be plain instance methods.

Comment: cool, that makes perfect sense. Thank you!.

In regards to your side-note... if I returned tuples instead of formatted strings would I only ever format the tuple on the front end?

Comment: @alpine.lines: Yup. A potentially useful `staticmethod` might be one that takes some sequence of `tuple`s and formats it the way your existing code does, so if formatting is performed semi-commonly, it's easy for the caller to do so. It's appropriate to `staticmethod` because it does use a structure commonly used by the class, but it would be generalized (so a caller rearrange, combine, and filter chords from multiple methods, then format them for display with the utility).

Comment: cool thank you all so much. I think I am making pretty quick progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code broken into instance methods vs static methods vs functional.
There are trade-offs obviously ... commented on already so I will not beat a dead horse. ;)

```
# with INSTANCE methods
################################################################################
class ChordSheet:
    notes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]

    def __init__(self, root):
        index = self.notes.index(root)

        self.root = root
        self.major = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index + 4) % 12],
                      self.notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        self.minor = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index + 3) % 12],
                      self.notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        # self.perfect_fifth = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index+x)%12], self.notes[(index+x)%12]]
        # self.diminished_fifth = [self.notes[index], self.notes[(index+x)%12], self.notes[(index+x)%12]]
        # self.major_seventh = []
        # self.minor_seventh = []
        # self.diminished_seventh = []

    def get_root(self):  # static?
        return "Root: {}".format(self.root)

    def get_major(self):  # static?
        return "Major Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.major[0],
                                                          self.major[1],
                                                          self.major[2],
                                                          self.major[0],
                                                          self.major[2],
                                                          self.major[1])

    def get_minor(self):  # static?
        return "Minor Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(self.minor[0],
                                                          self.minor[1],
                                                          self.minor[2],
                                                          self.minor[0],
                                                          self.minor[2],
                                                          self.minor[1])

    def first_inverted_major(self):  # static?
        return "First Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            self.major[1], self.major[2], self.major[0], self.major[1],
            self.major[0], self.major[2])

    def first_inverted_minor(self):  # static?
        return "First Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            self.minor[1], self.minor[2], self.minor[0], self.minor[1],
            self.minor[0], self.minor[2])

    def second_inverted_major(self):  # static?
        return "Second Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            self.major[2], self.major[0], self.major[1], self.major[2],
            self.major[1], self.major[0])

    def second_inverted_minor(self):  # static?
        return "Second Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            self.minor[2], self.minor[0], self.minor[1], self.minor[2],
            self.minor[1], self.minor[0])


# with STATIC methods
################################################################################
class ChordSheetAlt:

    @staticmethod
    def get_root(root):
        return "Root: {}".format(root)

    @staticmethod
    def get_major(root, notes):
        index = notes.index(root)
        major = [notes[index], notes[(index + 4) % 12],
                      notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        return "Major Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(major[0],
                                                          major[1],
                                                          major[2],
                                                          major[0],
                                                          major[2],
                                                          major[1])

    @staticmethod
    def get_minor(root, notes):
        index = notes.index(root)
        minor = [notes[index], notes[(index + 3) % 12],
                      notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        return "Minor Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(minor[0],
                                                          minor[1],
                                                          minor[2],
                                                          minor[0],
                                                          minor[2],
                                                          minor[1])

    @staticmethod
    def first_inverted_major(root, notes):
        index = notes.index(root)
        major = [notes[index], notes[(index + 4) % 12],
                      notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        return "First Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            major[1], major[2], major[0], major[1],
            major[0], major[2])

    @staticmethod
    def first_inverted_minor(root, notes):
        index = notes.index(root)
        minor = [notes[index], notes[(index + 3) % 12],
                      notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        return "First Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            minor[1], minor[2], minor[0], minor[1],
            minor[0], minor[2])

    @staticmethod
    def second_inverted_major(root, notes):
        root = root
        index = notes.index(root)
        major = [notes[index], notes[(index + 4) % 12],
                      notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        return "Second Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            major[2], major[0], major[1], major[2],
            major[1], major[0])

    @staticmethod
    def second_inverted_minor(root, notes):
        index = notes.index(root)
        minor = [notes[index], notes[(index + 3) % 12],
                      notes[(index + 7) % 12]]
        return "Second Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(
            minor[2], minor[0], minor[1], minor[2],
            minor[1], minor[0])


# refactor ChordSheetAlt class to FUNCTIONAL
# since its chock full of static methods, i.e. stand-alone functions
# might as well convert fully to FUNCTIONAL
################################################################################

def get_root_chord(root):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    return "Root: {}".format(root)

def get_index(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    return notes.index(root)

def compose_major(index, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    return [notes[index], notes[(index + 4) % 12],notes[(index + 7) % 12]]

def compose_minor(index, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    return [notes[index], notes[(index + 3) % 12],notes[(index + 7) % 12]]

def get_major_chords(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    index = get_index(root, notes)
    major = compose_major(index, notes)
    return "Major Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(major[0],
                                                      major[1],
                                                      major[2],
                                                      major[0],
                                                      major[2],
                                                      major[1])

def get_minor_chords(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    index = get_index(root, notes)
    minor = compose_minor(index, notes)
    return "Minor Chord: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(minor[0],
                                                      minor[1],
                                                      minor[2],
                                                      minor[0],
                                                      minor[2],
                                                      minor[1])

def first_inverted_major_chords(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    index = get_index(root, notes)
    major = compose_major(index, notes)
    return "First Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(major[1],
                                                                major[2],
                                                                major[0],
                                                                major[1],
                                                                major[0],
                                                                major[2])

def first_inverted_minor_chords(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    index = get_index(root, notes)
    minor = compose_minor(index, notes)
    return "First Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(minor[1],
                                                                minor[2],
                                                                minor[0],
                                                                minor[1],
                                                                minor[0],
                                                                minor[2])

def second_inverted_major_chords(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    index = get_index(root, notes)
    major = compose_major(index, notes)
    return "Second Major Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(major[2],
                                                                 major[0],
                                                                 major[1],
                                                                 major[2],
                                                                 major[1],
                                                                 major[0])

def second_inverted_minor_chords(root, notes):
    # add type/constraint/error, etc. handling logic
    index = get_index(root, notes)
    minor = compose_minor(index, notes)
    return "Second Minor Inversion: {} {} {} or {} {} {}".format(minor[2],
                                                                 minor[0],
                                                                 minor[1],
                                                                 minor[2],
                                                                 minor[1],
                                                                 minor[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('\nclass with instance methods:')
    print('-'*79)
    sheet = ChordSheet(root='D')
    print(sheet.get_root())
    print(sheet.get_major())
    print(sheet.get_minor())
    print(sheet.first_inverted_major())
    print(sheet.first_inverted_minor())
    print(sheet.second_inverted_major())
    print(sheet.second_inverted_minor())


    # STATIC
    print('\nclass with static methods:')
    print('-'*79)
    mynotes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
    print(ChordSheetAlt.get_root(root='D'))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.get_major(root='D',notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.get_minor(root='D',notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.first_inverted_major(root='D',notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.first_inverted_minor(root='D',notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.second_inverted_major(root='D',notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.second_inverted_minor(root='D',notes=mynotes))


    # STATIC
    print('\nclass with static methods (arbitrary input list):')
    print('-'*79)
    mynotes = [i for i in range(15)]
    print(ChordSheetAlt.get_root(root=2))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.get_major(root=2,notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.get_minor(root=2,notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.first_inverted_major(root=2,notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.first_inverted_minor(root=2,notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.second_inverted_major(root=2,notes=mynotes))
    print(ChordSheetAlt.second_inverted_minor(root=2,notes=mynotes))


    # FUNCTIONAL
    print('\nfunctional programming style:')
    print('-'*79)
    mynotes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
    root = 'D'
    root_and_notes = (root, mynotes)
    print(get_root_chord(root))
    print(get_major_chords(*root_and_notes))
    print(get_minor_chords(*root_and_notes))
    print(first_inverted_major_chords(*root_and_notes))
    print(first_inverted_minor_chords(*root_and_notes))
    print(second_inverted_major_chords(*root_and_notes))
    print(second_inverted_minor_chords(*root_and_notes))
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, the extra info about functional programming is awesome. I really appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 2):

From [this post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/#static-methods):

> This type of method takes neither a self nor a cls parameter (but of
>   course it’s free to accept an arbitrary number of other parameters).
>
> Therefore a static method can neither modify object state nor class
>   state. Static methods are restricted in what data they can access -
>   and they’re primarily a way to namespace your methods.

Meaning sometimes its useful to have a semi-related function which belongs to the namespace of `Chord_Sheet` (i.e. function `foo` called using `Chord_Sheet.foo()`). It cannot interact with the object state as it does not take `self` as an argument and thus cannot use `self.root` etc.